How tabindex works in angular
How to change tabindex from mid of the page at the time of loading in the angular.
I tried using tabindex=0 but no result. When I press tab focus is going on logo but I want it should go to mid of the page and focus on the button.

The default value of tabindex is 0 already, so all elements have that index by default. Generally, it's a bad idea to mess with the tab order of a document, since assistive technologies use it for everything. If you start messing with it, you end up having to change the tabindex of every focusable element on the page dynamically, and that gets old really quickly.
